# Don't see attributes (columns) in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm following a course on edX and I'm using the AdventureWorksLT database for the exercises, everything seems fine.

However, in the Object Explorer I can't see the attributes (columns) of a table.

When I expand the table I see 4 subfolders:

- Keys (which generates an error when I try to open it)
- Constraints
- Triggers
- Statistics

No attributes/columns of the table.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I really need this sometimes to see, for instance, the type of attribute (i.e. varchar or int).

The database is hosted on Microsoft Azure and I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and database.

[image: My object explorer in MS SQL Server management studio]

Comment: which user you are logged in with?

Comment: With my own username which is as far as I know the administrator. I wil take a look in the Azure environment to be sure.

Comment: Yeps, I'm logged with administrator rights

Comment: @seethestars i've been working for some time with Azure SQL and if I'm right you can't see them. It's an azure thing, not a problem for your account.

Comment: @CiucaS thanks for your answer, but thats kind of crazy isn't it? Anyone an idea how I now can see the properties of the attributes (Length, type, etc).

Comment: The T-SQL command `sp_help <objectname>` will return object metadata

Comment: @seethestars select the table name ( http://imgur.com/a/VE09Y )  and click Alt+F1

Comment: @Ed Harper, I can't execute this command, I got an error.

Comment: @CicuaS, this combination (Alt + F1) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you installed the *latest* version of SSMS? SSMS is now a *separate* free product. The latest version is 16.5.3, available for download [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)